# ¿Cómo configurar Sublime Text 3 para C#?

Tags: c#, sublimetext3

Quisiera saber cómo puedo instalar el compilador de *C#* para trabajar con *Sublime Text 3*. Ya intenté instalar el *OmniSharp* desde el *Package Control* pero no está en la lista que despliega, y tambien intenté con:

```
{ 
    "cmd": [
        "%WINDIR%Microsoft.NETFrameworkv4.0.30319csc.exe /utf8output /nologo",
        "$file_name", "&&", "$file_base_name.exe"
    ], 
    "shell": true 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abre la cmd en modo Administrador.

Muevete a la carpeta:

```
 cd {ruta al directorio de plugins de ST3}/Packages
```

Clona el repositorio:

```
git clone https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-sublime.git OmniSharp
```

Entra a la nueva carpeta creada:

```
cd OmniSharp
```

Y actualizala:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

También debes actualizar la build:

```
build.cmd
```

El servidor buscará automaticamente la solución al archivo de la carpeta que has abierto en ST3. Si tienes varias soluciones tienes que especficiar el archivo que deseas usar en sublime-project.

Ves a Archivo -> Abrir y selecciona la carpeta con tu solución.

Ves a Proyecto -> Guardar proyecto como y guarda un ELNOMBREDETUPROYECTO.sublime-project en la misma ruta que tu *.sln

Abre tu ELNOMBREDETUPROYECTO.sublime-project archivo que deberia aparecer en la barra de la derecha.

Accede a la localización del archivo *.sln como muestro aquí abajo:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "solution_file": "./testconsoleprj.sln"
}
```

Una vez hecho esto deberás:

Guardar TUPROYECTO.sublime-project
Cerrar sublime
Abrir Sublime
Click Proyecto -> Abrir Proyecto y selecciona tu TUPROYECTO.sublime-project

Imagen de como configurar lenguaje específico de C#
[image: Imagen]
Y copia esto en el documento

```
{
   "auto_complete": true,
   "auto_complete_selector": "source - comment",
   "auto_complete_triggers": [ {"selector": "source.cs", "characters": ".<"} ],
}
```